# Flex DataGrid column width: one column to rule them all?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, layout, datagrid, flex4

I have a Flex 4, mx:DataGrid with the following (pertinent) properties set:

```
width="100%"
horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
```

I have the `minWidth` set on all of the `DataGridColumns` and the width set on one of them. If I simply maximize/minimize the display (in browser or stand-alone flash player) of the application, the columns scale up and down nicely. But if you grab the edge of the application and drag it to make it bigger, only one column grows really big. When you drag the size down again, the one column **remains** big, but all of the other columns get squished way down.

Is this a bug in the Flex DataGrid, or am I just missing a key property (or properties on the datagrid columns) to set, to make all columns grow and shrink when you drag-enlarge the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an unpleasant anomaly, if not an actual bug, in the way Flex does datagrids. In Adobe's defense, figuring out how to resize all the columns appears not to be a trivial task.

The way I've always handled this is to make a dummy column at the end, with a minWidth of 4 and no width specification. Then that becomes the "expandable column" that takes up the slack. Then I make sure to allow the rest of the columns enough room to display their data and their header renderers from the start by giving each a minWidth and a width. The only time I have problems is if there are too many columns to display in the space allowed, in which case you get a horizontal scrollbar and all (or most) bets are off.

Comment: But then when you stretch the grid/application, the only column to expand will be the exandable one, right? So all this does is saves one of your "real" columns from being stretched out. Not sure this is a whole lot better...

Comment: My workaround's only advantage is that it prevents the ADG from triggering its poor column-width-adjustment heuristics. I do not offer it as a panacea.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem as follows:

in creationComplete  add

```
{  
.....
grd_Principal.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, resizeGrid);
grd_Principal.dispatchEvent(new ResizeEvent(ResizeEvent.RESIZE));
...
}

protected function resizeGrid(event:ResizeEvent):void
{
    grd_Principal.horizontalScrollPolicy = 'on';                // datagrid
    ..... your DataGridColumn
    dgc_nCdId.width = grd_Principal.width * 0.06;               //datagridcolumn in percent
    dgc_Excluir.width = 20;                                                     //normal
    dgc_cNmUsuario.width = grd_Principal.width * 0.226;

    grd_Principal.horizontalScrollPolicy = 'off';               
}
```

Comment: So you are manually setting the width of each column on every resize. Guess it might be helpful if this works, but kinda sucks to have to specify all the widths in code instead of in the MXML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try capturing the event, setting the horizontalScrollPolicy to On, letting Flex resize the columns itself, then setting horizontalScrollPolicy back to Off

Comment: Capturing which event? Some example code would be nice, as I'm pretty setting a property to true then false in an event handler wouldn't affect anything, as Flex/Flash is not multi-threaded.